# Apache echarts heatmap chart. How to add text in the legend and remove numbers

Tags: heatmap, echarts

I specifically would like to solve this for heatmap in echarts. Let's consider the following example, where in visualmap I chose type: 'piecewise'. In this case the result appears in the JS snippet. Instead of 0-2, 2-4, 4-6, 6-8,8-10 in the legend, I would like to have: very low, low, middle, high, very high. How can I achieve this. Your help is thoroughly appreciated.

```js
var chartDom = document.getElementById('main');
var myChart = echarts.init(chartDom);
var option;

// prettier-ignore
const hours = [
    '12a', '1a', '2a', '3a', '4a', '5a', '6a',
    '7a', '8a', '9a', '10a', '11a',
    '12p', '1p', '2p', '3p', '4p', '5p',
    '6p', '7p', '8p', '9p', '10p', '11p'
];
// prettier-ignore
const days = [
    'Saturday', 'Friday', 'Thursday',
    'Wednesday', 'Tuesday', 'Monday', 'Sunday'
];
// prettier-ignore
const data = [[0, 0, 5], [0, 1, 1], [0, 2, 0], [0, 3, 0], [0, 4, 0], [0, 5, 0], [0, 6, 0], [0, 7, 0], [0, 8, 0], [0, 9, 0], [0, 10, 0], [0, 11, 2], [0, 12, 4], [0, 13, 1], [0, 14, 1], [0, 15, 3], [0, 16, 4], [0, 17, 6], [0, 18, 4], [0, 19, 4], [0, 20, 3], [0, 21, 3], [0, 22, 2], [0, 23, 5], [1, 0, 7], [1, 1, 0], [1, 2, 0], [1, 3, 0], [1, 4, 0], [1, 5, 0], [1, 6, 0], [1, 7, 0], [1, 8, 0], [1, 9, 0], [1, 10, 5], [1, 11, 2], [1, 12, 2], [1, 13, 6], [1, 14, 9], [1, 15, 11], [1, 16, 6], [1, 17, 7], [1, 18, 8], [1, 19, 12], [1, 20, 5], [1, 21, 5], [1, 22, 7], [1, 23, 2], [2, 0, 1], [2, 1, 1], [2, 2, 0], [2, 3, 0], [2, 4, 0], [2, 5, 0], [2, 6, 0], [2, 7, 0], [2, 8, 0], [2, 9, 0], [2, 10, 3], [2, 11, 2], [2, 12, 1], [2, 13, 9], [2, 14, 8], [2, 15, 10], [2, 16, 6], [2, 17, 5], [2, 18, 5], [2, 19, 5], [2, 20, 7], [2, 21, 4], [2, 22, 2], [2, 23, 4], [3, 0, 7], [3, 1, 3], [3, 2, 0], [3, 3, 0], [3, 4, 0], [3, 5, 0], [3, 6, 0], [3, 7, 0], [3, 8, 1], [3, 9, 0], [3, 10, 5], [3, 11, 4], [3, 12, 7], [3, 13, 14], [3, 14, 13], [3, 15, 12], [3, 16, 9], [3, 17, 5], [3, 18, 5], [3, 19, 10], [3, 20, 6], [3, 21, 4], [3, 22, 4], [3, 23, 1], [4, 0, 1], [4, 1, 3], [4, 2, 0], [4, 3, 0], [4, 4, 0], [4, 5, 1], [4, 6, 0], [4, 7, 0], [4, 8, 0], [4, 9, 2], [4, 10, 4], [4, 11, 4], [4, 12, 2], [4, 13, 4], [4, 14, 4], [4, 15, 14], [4, 16, 12], [4, 17, 1], [4, 18, 8], [4, 19, 5], [4, 20, 3], [4, 21, 7], [4, 22, 3], [4, 23, 0], [5, 0, 2], [5, 1, 1], [5, 2, 0], [5, 3, 3], [5, 4, 0], [5, 5, 0], [5, 6, 0], [5, 7, 0], [5, 8, 2], [5, 9, 0], [5, 10, 4], [5, 11, 1], [5, 12, 5], [5, 13, 10], [5, 14, 5], [5, 15, 7], [5, 16, 11], [5, 17, 6], [5, 18, 0], [5, 19, 5], [5, 20, 3], [5, 21, 4], [5, 22, 2], [5, 23, 0], [6, 0, 1], [6, 1, 0], [6, 2, 0], [6, 3, 0], [6, 4, 0], [6, 5, 0], [6, 6, 0], [6, 7, 0], [6, 8, 0], [6, 9, 0], [6, 10, 1], [6, 11, 0], [6, 12, 2], [6, 13, 1], [6, 14, 3], [6, 15, 4], [6, 16, 0], [6, 17, 0], [6, 18, 0], [6, 19, 0], [6, 20, 1], [6, 21, 2], [6, 22, 2], [6, 23, 6]]
    .map(function (item) {
    return [item[1], item[0], item[2] || '-'];
});
option = {
  tooltip: {
    position: 'top'
  },
  grid: {
    height: '50%',
    top: '10%'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: hours,
    splitArea: {
      show: true
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: days,
    splitArea: {
      show: true
    }
  },
  visualMap: {
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    calculable: true,
    orient: 'horizontal',
    left: 'center',
    bottom: '15%',
    type: 'piecewise'
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Punch Card',
      type: 'heatmap',
      data: data,
      label: {
        show: true
      },
      emphasis: {
        itemStyle: {
          shadowBlur: 10,
          shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
        }
      }
    }
  ]
};

option && myChart.setOption(option);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/3.7.2/echarts.min.js"></script>
<div id="main" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use formatter;

https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#visualMap-piecewise.formatter

```js
var chartDom = document.getElementById('main');
var myChart = echarts.init(chartDom);
var option;

// prettier-ignore
const hours = [
  '12a', '1a', '2a', '3a', '4a', '5a', '6a',
  '7a', '8a', '9a', '10a', '11a',
  '12p', '1p', '2p', '3p', '4p', '5p',
  '6p', '7p', '8p', '9p', '10p', '11p'
];
// prettier-ignore
const days = [
  'Saturday', 'Friday', 'Thursday',
  'Wednesday', 'Tuesday', 'Monday', 'Sunday'
];

const legendFormatter = function(val) {
  if (val === '0-2') {
    return 'very low'
  } else if (val === '2-4') {
    return 'low'
  } else if (val === '4-6') {
    return 'middle'
  } else if (val === '6-8') {
    return 'high'
  } else if (val === '8-10') {
    return 'very high'
  } else {
    return val
  }
}
// prettier-ignore
const data = [
    [0, 0, 5],
    [0, 1, 1],
    [0, 2, 0],
    [0, 3, 0],
    [0, 4, 0],
    [0, 5, 0],
    [0, 6, 0],
    [0, 7, 0],
    [0, 8, 0],
    [0, 9, 0],
    [0, 10, 0],
    [0, 11, 2],
    [0, 12, 4],
    [0, 13, 1],
    [0, 14, 1],
    [0, 15, 3],
    [0, 16, 4],
    [0, 17, 6],
    [0, 18, 4],
    [0, 19, 4],
    [0, 20, 3],
    [0, 21, 3],
    [0, 22, 2],
    [0, 23, 5],
    [1, 0, 7],
    [1, 1, 0],
    [1, 2, 0],
    [1, 3, 0],
    [1, 4, 0],
    [1, 5, 0],
    [1, 6, 0],
    [1, 7, 0],
    [1, 8, 0],
    [1, 9, 0],
    [1, 10, 5],
    [1, 11, 2],
    [1, 12, 2],
    [1, 13, 6],
    [1, 14, 9],
    [1, 15, 11],
    [1, 16, 6],
    [1, 17, 7],
    [1, 18, 8],
    [1, 19, 12],
    [1, 20, 5],
    [1, 21, 5],
    [1, 22, 7],
    [1, 23, 2],
    [2, 0, 1],
    [2, 1, 1],
    [2, 2, 0],
    [2, 3, 0],
    [2, 4, 0],
    [2, 5, 0],
    [2, 6, 0],
    [2, 7, 0],
    [2, 8, 0],
    [2, 9, 0],
    [2, 10, 3],
    [2, 11, 2],
    [2, 12, 1],
    [2, 13, 9],
    [2, 14, 8],
    [2, 15, 10],
    [2, 16, 6],
    [2, 17, 5],
    [2, 18, 5],
    [2, 19, 5],
    [2, 20, 7],
    [2, 21, 4],
    [2, 22, 2],
    [2, 23, 4],
    [3, 0, 7],
    [3, 1, 3],
    [3, 2, 0],
    [3, 3, 0],
    [3, 4, 0],
    [3, 5, 0],
    [3, 6, 0],
    [3, 7, 0],
    [3, 8, 1],
    [3, 9, 0],
    [3, 10, 5],
    [3, 11, 4],
    [3, 12, 7],
    [3, 13, 14],
    [3, 14, 13],
    [3, 15, 12],
    [3, 16, 9],
    [3, 17, 5],
    [3, 18, 5],
    [3, 19, 10],
    [3, 20, 6],
    [3, 21, 4],
    [3, 22, 4],
    [3, 23, 1],
    [4, 0, 1],
    [4, 1, 3],
    [4, 2, 0],
    [4, 3, 0],
    [4, 4, 0],
    [4, 5, 1],
    [4, 6, 0],
    [4, 7, 0],
    [4, 8, 0],
    [4, 9, 2],
    [4, 10, 4],
    [4, 11, 4],
    [4, 12, 2],
    [4, 13, 4],
    [4, 14, 4],
    [4, 15, 14],
    [4, 16, 12],
    [4, 17, 1],
    [4, 18, 8],
    [4, 19, 5],
    [4, 20, 3],
    [4, 21, 7],
    [4, 22, 3],
    [4, 23, 0],
    [5, 0, 2],
    [5, 1, 1],
    [5, 2, 0],
    [5, 3, 3],
    [5, 4, 0],
    [5, 5, 0],
    [5, 6, 0],
    [5, 7, 0],
    [5, 8, 2],
    [5, 9, 0],
    [5, 10, 4],
    [5, 11, 1],
    [5, 12, 5],
    [5, 13, 10],
    [5, 14, 5],
    [5, 15, 7],
    [5, 16, 11],
    [5, 17, 6],
    [5, 18, 0],
    [5, 19, 5],
    [5, 20, 3],
    [5, 21, 4],
    [5, 22, 2],
    [5, 23, 0],
    [6, 0, 1],
    [6, 1, 0],
    [6, 2, 0],
    [6, 3, 0],
    [6, 4, 0],
    [6, 5, 0],
    [6, 6, 0],
    [6, 7, 0],
    [6, 8, 0],
    [6, 9, 0],
    [6, 10, 1],
    [6, 11, 0],
    [6, 12, 2],
    [6, 13, 1],
    [6, 14, 3],
    [6, 15, 4],
    [6, 16, 0],
    [6, 17, 0],
    [6, 18, 0],
    [6, 19, 0],
    [6, 20, 1],
    [6, 21, 2],
    [6, 22, 2],
    [6, 23, 6]
  ]
  .map(function(item) {
    return [item[1], item[0], item[2] || '-'];
  });
option = {
  tooltip: {
    position: 'top'
  },
  grid: {
    height: '50%',
    top: '10%'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: hours,
    splitArea: {
      show: true
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: days,
    splitArea: {
      show: true
    }
  },
  visualMap: {
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    calculable: true,
    orient: 'horizontal',
    left: 'center',
    bottom: '15%',
    type: 'piecewise',
    formatter: function(value, value2) {
      return legendFormatter(`${value}-${value2}`);
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Punch Card',
    type: 'heatmap',
    data: data,
    label: {
      show: true
    },
    emphasis: {
      itemStyle: {
        shadowBlur: 10,
        shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
      }
    }
  }]
};

option && myChart.setOption(option);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/3.7.2/echarts.min.js"></script>
<div id="main" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
```